# Decimal point with remainder

Tags: objective-c

I need help with my calculator app.I'm using two float variables so when I do an exercise account, for example 6/2 the result is 3.000000 (with decimal point) and not 3 because it is a float variable. However, if I do 2/6 the result is 0.33333,How can I fix the problem that show the decimal point only if have a remainder.

Here's the code:

```
//Add the number to UILabel
-(IBAction)numberPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

NSString *number = sender.currentTitle;
if (self.typingNumber) {
    self.firstLabel.text = [self.firstLabel.text stringByAppendingString:number];
}
else {

    self.firstLabel.text = number;
    self.typingNumber = YES;

   }

}

//Equal method
-(IBAction)equalPress:(id)sender {


self.typingNumber = NO;
self.secondNum = [self.firstLabel.text floatValue];
result = 0;

if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
    result = self.firstNum + self.secondNum;
   }
if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
    result = self.firstNum - self.secondNum;
   }
if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"X"]) {
    result = self.firstNum * self.secondNum;
   }
if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
    result = self.firstNum / self.secondNum;
   }

self.firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f" ,result];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `%g` format specification:

> The double argument shall be converted in the style f or e (or in the style F or E in the case of a G conversion specifier), with the precision specifying the number of significant digits. If an explicit precision is zero, it shall be taken as 1. The style used depends on the value converted; style e (or E ) shall be used only if the exponent resulting from such a conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision. **Trailing zeros shall be removed from the fractional portion of the result**; a radix character shall appear only if it is followed by a digit or a '#' flag is present.

from [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) as used by Apple, **emphasis** added.

For example:

```
float a = 6.0 / 2.0;
float b = 2.0 / 6.0;
NSLog(@"%f, %g | %f, %g", a, a, b, b);
```

produces:

```
3.000000, 3 | 0.333333, 0.333333
```

For even more control use the `NSNumberFormatter` class, in particular look at properties such as `alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator`.

For example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = NO;

NSLog(@"%@ | %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(a)], [formatter stringFromNumber:@(b)]);
```

produces:

```
3 | 0.333
```

(you can use other properties to control the number of decimal places etc.)